# Exposing private base class name with `using` in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer, private, using

In a situation when some struct `D` inherits another struct `A` twice: once privately via `B` and the second time publicly via `C`, is it allowed to write `using B::A` in `D`?

```
struct A {};
class B : A {};
struct C : A {};
struct D : B, C { 
    using B::A;  //ok in GCC, error in Clang
};
```

The program is accepted by GCC, but Clang prints the error:

```
error: 'A' is a private member of 'A'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5jeqrzorE

`using B::A` must just expose injected class name `A` from `D`. On the one hand, `A` is already available to use in `D` (so GCC accepts it), but on the other hand `A` is private within `B` (so Clang rejects it). Which one compiler is right here?

Answer (score 1):

[[class.access.base]/5](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.access.base#5):

> The access to a member is affected by the class in which the member is named. This naming class is the class in whose scope name lookup performed a search that found the member.

The naming class in this case is `B`. Since `A` as a member of `B` is private, it is not accessible in `D`, making the *using-declaration* ill-formed.

Answer (score -1):

It would somehow cause ambiguity in this case. The class lookup needs to be ignored when checking `A`. GCC should be correct since `B::A` and `C::A` refer to the same `A` from `D`.
Even clang could not detect the error if `using C::A` is added

```
struct A {};
struct B :  A {};
struct C : A {};
struct D : C, B { 
    using B::A;  //ok in Clang, error in GCC
    using C::A;
};
```

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.udecl#1

Comment: You replaced `class B` with `struct B` in your code. This changes the inheritance type from private to public.

Comment: I just want to show the clang's behavior is not correct in that case